# Selecting by location: Line to Line

Tags: arcmap, openstreetmap, select-by-location

I am trying to select line features from an OSM road shapefile layer (Layer 1) based on the features of a line layer (Layer 2). Layer 2 is selected road segments from Layer 1 produced using a routing plugin in QGIS

What I want to do now is to select the road segments from layer 2 to layer 1. I am using the `"Select by Location"` tool on ArcMap using `"intersect"` as a spatial selection method but it selects segments that I do not want to be included.

I tried to use other spatial selection methods but to no avail- they do not select exactly the segments I want. The picture below shows "are within the source layer feature".

[image: Red shows Layer 2, Green is Layer 1]

Comment: Have you tried "Share a line segment with..."?